# where the translated native libs are located on android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering, frida

i am reverse engineering this android app running on android studio emulator
the app dosent have any libs for x86 it only has libs for arm and the app is making native calls and getting a result back, i know android studio have lib translation but when i inspect the native libraries loaded into memory using frida and objection i only find the .odex of the app no sign for the apps libs?
also when i inspect the maps file located in /proc/$pid/maps of the target app i found the following

```
bd1d3000-bd229000 rw-p 00a4a000 fd:05 40968       /data/app/~~WjE28KNs/com.app.android--Hm5k3FQw==/lib/arm/libclient.so
```

im not sure if this means its loaded but i geuss bd1d3000-bd229000 is the memory address? how would i go to inspect what this addresses contain?

Comment: You are not the first running into this problem. Until someone has reversed the way Google uses to run ARM code in an x86 emulator I would recommend to use a real ARM device instead of an emulator.

Comment: Note that the library is not mapped as executable. I surmise that means that the [propietary ARM to x86 translation library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/03/run-arm-apps-on-android-emulator.html) traps jumps into the library and does .. something.

Comment: @Robert  i don think the translation is done by qemu part becuase if it was that case then the earlier version of android studio emulator images say android 10 will be able to install arm apps and run them which is not the case sadly the arm libs translation is done in a .so lib and there is no public code for it reversing it will be very hard so the only solution i found was to use a arm sys image it pretty slow but it works